# Is there a way to convert a single LightGBM decision tree (decision rules) to Python code (conditional statements)?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree, lightgbm

I am trying to convert a single LightGBM decision tree i.e. num_boost_round = 1 with num_leaves = 16 to Python conditional statements. Is there a way to do this? I found a post on stackoverflow about doing this with the sklearn decision tree implementation but that does not directly apply to my case.